# Using `boot()` on a model conflicts with RevisionableTrait

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, traits, revisionable

I'm using the [Revisionable](https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable) package in my laravel app to log edits to a model.

In addition I have also implemented an observer class to listen for specific model events (update, delete, create etc) and perform actions (such as clear caches etc). This observer is instantiated in the model using the `boot()` method as follows:

```
class Client {
    use \Venturecraft\Revisionable\RevisionableTrait;
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        Client::observe(new App\Observers\ClientObserver);
    }
}
```

What I find is that when I define a `boot()` method in my model the Revisionable Trait stops working and does not log changes - presumably because it too uses a `boot` method that is being overridden by the one in the model.

How would I fix this to allow listening for model events as well as utilizing the Revisionable package?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939166/how-to-override-trait-function-and-call-it-from-the-overriden-function

Answer (score 0):

this link helped me

https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable/issues/175

I used in laravel 5.1 i hope it will work to you

```
use RevisionableTrait, UuidTrait {
        UuidTrait::boot insteadof RevisionableTrait;
    }
```