# Call own method from trait

Tags: php, inheritance, traits

I have a class which extends an other class and uses a trait.

```
class A extends ABase
{
    use MyTrait;
    //...
}
```

The extended class (`ABase`) extends an other class (`ABase2`), which extends an abstract class (`ABase3`).

When an `A` class is created, the trait constructor is executed because there is no constructor defined in `A`. At the same time, the trait constructor calls a method (`configureOptions`) which is defined in the trait, but also in the abstract class `ABase3` with the same visibility (protected).

```
trait MyTrait
{
    public function __construct($options)
    {
        //...
        $this->configureOptions($resolver);
       //... 
    }

    protected function configureOptions($resolver)
    {
        // Define options
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is that when `configureOptions` is called from the trait, the method executed is not the method defined in the trait, but the one defined in the abstract class (`ABase3`).

As [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) says: *An inherited member from a base class is overridden by a member inserted by a Trait. The precedence order is that members from the current class override Trait methods, which in turn override inherited methods.*

Doesn't say nothing about calling methods from the same trait, but shouldn't check first for the methods inside its own class?

**Edit:**

Not only the abstract class (`ABase3`) has the `configureOptions` method, but also the A class, but again, the method called from the trait should call the own class method. Isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939166/how-to-override-trait-function-and-call-it-from-the-overriden-function#answer-11939306).

```
class A extends ABase
{
    use MyTrait {
        configureOptions as traitConfigureOptions;
    }
    //...
}
```

and then, instead of `parent::configureOptions($resolver)`:

```
$this->traitConfigureOptions($resolver);
```