# Laravel controller use trait that uses another used trait

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7, traits

I have a controller that uses two traits, `CavityTools` and `OperationTools`

```
class OperationController extends Controller
{

    use \App\Traits\CavityTools;
    use \App\Traits\OperationTools;
```

However, the second trait `OperationTools using`CavityTools`:

```
trait OperationTools {
    use \App\Traits\CavityTools;
```

So when I try to use a method of `OperationTools` from any controller's method such as `$this->getProduction()`, I have got an error tells about a method in the `CavityTools` that it is not applied due to collision:

> Trait method cavityPerformanceBetweenTimes has not been applied,
>   because there are collisions with other trait methods on
>   App\Http\Controllers\OperationController

I have tried to to alias the second trait, `use \App\Traits\OperationTools as OpTs;` but it generate parse error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS), expecting ',' or
>   ';' or '{'

How could I solve this issue?

Comment: Why don't you just use the `OperationTools` trait, since it uses `CavityTools` already inside your controllers? `class Ctrl { use OperationTools; //rest of the class }` see example http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/00d35ec51050fab3f5ebc1348b7bebf8ec720f5d

Comment: @Kyslik because there are another controller's actions uses another methods of `CavityTools` directly. However, it is good idea, I will check it soon.

Comment: When interpreting code traits are just copied inside the class, there is nothing special about them its kind of same concept like *extending* class. I fail to understand your latest comment. I am also surprised that you have 7k rep and mostly from PHP and do not know this. Really weird.

Comment: Your comment make it clear, I mistakenly realized that each trait may works as isolated capsule but I did not think that it works like PHP include, i.e each trait that use another trait, it will bring its methods with it.

Comment: you could rename one of them checkout this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39441612/php-trait-override-protected-trait-method/39441990#39441990

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `OperationTools` trait since `CavityTools` are already used.

Example code:

```
<?php


trait A {
    function a() {
        echo "a trait\n";
    }
}

trait B {
    use A;
    function b() {
        echo "b trait\n";
    }

    function a() {
        echo "a fcn from trait B\n";
    }
}

trait C {
    use B;
    function a() {
        echo "a fcn from C trait\n";
    }

    function b() {
        echo "b fcn from C trait\n";
    }
}


class AClass {
    use A;
}

$classA = new AClass;
$classA->a();
// $classB->b(); // will throw up


class BClass {
    use B;
}

$classB = new BClass;
$classB->a();
$classB->b();

class CClass {
    use C;
}

$classC = new CClass;
$classC->a();
$classC->b();
```

// output

```
a trait
a fcn from trait B
b trait
a fcn from C trait
b fcn from C trait
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because there are same functions in both traits. To avoid that you will have to use "InsteadOf" in your current class.

Reference - [Collisions with other trait methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064470/collisions-with-other-trait-methods/25064632)