# Laravel 5.3 - changing auth view paths

Tags: laravel-5.3

In my Laravel app I have different auth for administrators and users. So I have separete views as well. I have placed auth `views` folder inside `admin` folder, so that the view path to my admin auth is now `admin.auth.login` for example. Where can I change those paths so that I can use them for all the auth functions?

Answer (score 6):

If you take a look at your `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php`, you will see:

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;
```

It's a [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php), you can find all the login related method over there in `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php`.

There's a method in the trait which show the view as below:

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    return view('auth.login');
}
```

What you want to do is either:

- Copy the traits out to your own one and modify the `showLoginForm` method.

or

- Override the method `showLoginForm` in your `LoginController.php`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939166/how-to-override-trait-function-and-call-it-from-the-overriden-function)

Comment: Yes, I had to change for each auth function login, register, forgot/reset password new view paths with overwriting the functions in my controller. I just hoped that there would be a shorter way of doing that.