# Extending a trait conflicts with itself

Tags: php, traits

I'm trying to extend a trait. By that I mean create a trait that redefines a couple methods for a different trait.

This is my code (PHP 5.6 and Laravel 5.4):

```
namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasTimestamps;

trait ExtendHasTimestamps
{
    use HasTimestamps {
        HasTimestamps::setCreatedAt as parentSetCreatedAt;
        HasTimestamps::setUpdatedAt as parentSetUpdatedAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt($value) {
        if ($value !== '') return $this;
        return $this->parentSetCreatedAt($value);
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt($value) {
        if ($value !== '') return $this;
        return $this->parentSetUpdatedAt($value);
    }
}
```

The issue comes in when I use `ExtendHasTimestamps` in a Model, it conflicts with `HasTimestamps` because `Eloquent\Model` has `use HasTimestamps`. Before PHP 7, traits throw a fatal error if you try to define the same property twice. So since I'm defining `$timestamps` both in `HasTimestamps` and again through `ExtendHasTimestamps` by virtue of `use HasTimestamps`, it breaks.

In short:

```
trait HasTimestamps {
    protected $timestamps = true; //problematic property
}

trait ExtendHasTimestamps {
    use HasTimestamps;
    // add validation then call HasTimestamps method
}

class Model {
    use HasTimestamps;
}

class MyModel extends Model {
    use ExtendHasTimestamps; //everything breaks
}
```

Is there a way to either convince PHP that it is really the same thing and it can stop conflicting with itself, or to inform the class I'm working with (an extension of `Eloquent\Model`) to stop using `HasTimestamps` in favor of my trait?

---

<sub>[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939166/how-to-override-trait-function-and-call-it-from-the-overridden-function) does not answer mine because I'm trying to use a trait to overwrite another trait rather than just adding methods to each class where I need to use this code.</sub>

Comment: What you're doing in the `ExtendHasTimestamps` trait seems like a fix, any chance you might override or replace the original trait instead of providing your own ?

Comment: Unfortunately they are Laravel vendor files, which means that if I edit either `Eloquent\Model` or `HasTimestamps` it will get undone next time I run `composer update` or the like.

Comment: How about forgetting the trait and extending the base model class to implement your fixes ? (and make your model classes extend that new base class instead of Laravel's)

Comment: Yeah. That would work. I'll probably end up doing that. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry mate, I would have provided a full-fledged answer but I have no Laravel setup here to test it properly. Here is the link I found https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-override-base-model-some-methods-in-laravel-51

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you don't really need to extend the trait in the first place. I would simply override the methods in a trait used in your child class, then call the `parent` methods within the trait.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/2DqZQ

```
<?php

trait HasTimestamps
{
    protected $timestamps = true;

    public function setCreatedAt($value)
    {
        echo 'HasTimestamps::setCreatedAt'.PHP_EOL;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt($value)
    {
        echo 'HasTimestamps::setUpdatedAt'.PHP_EOL;
        return $this;
    }
}

trait ExtendHasTimestamps
{
    public function setCreatedAt($value)
    {
        echo 'ExtendHasTimestamps::setCreatedAt'.PHP_EOL;

        if ($value !== '') return $this;

        return parent::setCreatedAt($value);
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt($value)
    {
        echo 'ExtendHasTimestamps::setUpdatedAt'.PHP_EOL;

        if ($value !== '') return $this;

        return parent::setUpdatedAt($value);
    }
}

class Model
{
    use HasTimestamps;
}

class MyModel extends Model
{
    use ExtendHasTimestamps;
}

(new MyModel)->setCreatedAt('');

echo PHP_EOL;

(new MyModel)->setCreatedAt('time');
```

> ExtendHasTimestamps::setCreatedAt
>   HasTimestamps::setCreatedAt
>
> ExtendHasTimestamps::setCreatedAt

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this doesn't allow me to call the original HT method from the EHT method. Short of just copying the code wholesale.

Comment: I'm unsure what the `bar` method is for. But I need `EHT::setCreatedAt` to be able to call `HT::setCreatedAt` so that after it runs my code, it still does what Laravel thinks it is supposed to be doing

Comment: @amflare ah ok that makes sense, sorry I misunderstood. yeah, all you have to do is call `parent` within your trait's method. I've updated my answer and demo to demonstrate.

Comment: That is deceptively simple. Thanks.