# Laravel custom password email

Tags: laravel

I use laravel 5.6 and I succesfully send view as email.

I use this code :

```
Mail::to($user->email)->send(new Welcome($user));
```

My only problem is for password reset. I know I can customize a bit the template but how to override the default email template and send my own view ?

I try to write my own ResetPasswordNotification :

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class ResetPasswordNotification extends ResetPassword
{
/**
 * Build the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    if (static::$toMailCallback) {
        return call_user_func(static::$toMailCallback, $notifiable, $this->token);
    }

    return (new MailMessage)
        ->line('Vous recevez cet email car une demande de modification du mot de passe pour votre compte a été initialisée.')
        ->action('Réinitialiser le mot de passe', url(config('app.url').route('password.reset', $this->token, false)))
        ->line('Si vous n\'êtes pas à l\'origine de cette demande, merci de contacter l\'équipe du site.');
}
}
```

But I can only translate the email. What I want is to send my own view according to my own template.

Is it possible ?

Thank for your help.

Comment: Instead of returning `MailMessage` you can return your own mailable class with custom view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own view with `MailMessage`

Example:

```
return (new MailMessage)->view(
    'your.email.blade', [
        'data' => $data
    ]
);
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/notifications#mail-notifications for more info.

**Edit:**

Since you are using the password reset notification, you'll need to find the user first. I believe the `$notifiable` object in the `toMail` should be an instance of the `CanResetPassword` trait, so you'll have to look for the user with the email:

```
public function toMail($notifiable) {
{
    $email = $notifiable->getEmailForPasswordReset();
    $user = User::where('email', '=', $email)->first();

    return (new MailMessage)->view(
        'your.email.blade', [
            'user' => $user,
        ]
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank it work ! Is it possible to get user information ?

Comment: Ok I see but where do I add $user->notify ? I only copy toMail from ResetPasswordNotification

Comment: I've got this notify in my User controller, but it didn't know $user.

Comment: I've found an easy way, $notifiable contain user data

Comment: Yeah sorry, just realized it was for the password reset notification, which doesn't call the notification specifically from the user model.

Comment: Do you know how to prevent redirect after success ?

Comment: You'll have to override the `reset` function in your `ResetPasswordController`. The function is located inside the `ResetsPasswords` trait in your controller. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939166/how-to-override-trait-function-and-call-it-from-the-overridden-function for info on overriding trait functions.

Comment: I add sendResetResponse on my controller and erase everything except return $response, but I still be redirect.

Comment: Create a new issue with what you have so far and I can take a look at it

Comment: There you go if you have some time : https://stackoverflow.com/q/52086041/10139835 that k for your help for this case !