# Laravel reset email redirection

Tags: laravel

In my project I have one page to handle login form, register form and password reset form.

For the first two, everything work well. For the last, I find a way to send my own email instead of laravel's default email but now I want to stop redirect on success.

For the story, I launch a sweetalert notification when I click on submit, call reset controller with Ajax and wait for response.

But instead, page is reload on success. I don't find a way to prevent redirect and just send json to my Ajax.

My login.js :

```
$(".m_login_forget_password_submit").click(function(l){

    var t=$(this),r=$(this).closest("form");
    t.addClass("m-loader m-loader--right m-loader--light");

    swal({
        title:"Mot de passe",
        text:"Génération du lien.",
        type:"info"
    });
        var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'password/request',
            data: $this.serializeArray(),
            success:function(data){
                $("#m_login_signup_submit").toggleClass("m-loader m-loader--right m-loader--light");
                swal({
                    title:"Succès",
                    text:"Votre demande de compte a été transmise à nos équipe.",
                    type:"success"
                });

            },
            error: function(data){
                $("#m_login_signup_submit").toggleClass("m-loader m-loader--right m-loader--light");
                if( data.status === 422 ) {
                    var error = "Les erreurs suivantes ont été trouvées :";
                    var errors = data.responseJSON;
                    $.each( errors, function( key, value ) {
                        error += '<br>&#9656 ' + value[0];
                    });
                    swal("Erreur",error,"error")
                }
            }
        });
```

My custom ResetPasswordController :

```
class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
```

{

```
use ResetsPasswords;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

/**
 * Get the response for a successful password reset.
 *
 * @param  string  $response
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
protected function sendResetResponse($response)
{
    return 'ok';
}


    }
```

Someone know how to prevent redirect on send email reset password success and send json instead ?

Thank for your help.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I use version 5.6 of laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When resetting a password, the `reset` function will be called in your `ResetPasswordController`, so you'll have to rename your `sendResetResponse` function to `reset` (since you want to override the trait function) and point the default trait function to an unused function. Plus, if you want a JSON response, you'll need to specify that with the return.

Example:

```
class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    use ResetsPasswords {
        reset as unused;
    }

    ...

    //Override the trait function
    public function reset(Request $request) {
        //Call default validation and handle password change

        $this->validate($request, $this->rules(), $this->validationErrorMessages());

        // Here we will attempt to reset the user's password. If it is successful we
        // will update the password on an actual user model and persist it to the
        // database. Otherwise we will parse the error and return the response.
        $response = $this->broker()->reset(
            $this->credentials($request), function ($user, $password) {
                $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
            }
        );

        //Return the response
        if ($response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET) {
            return response()->json(array(
                'result' => 'ok',
            ), 200);
        } else {
            return response()->json(array(
                'result' => 'fail',
            ), 500);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Sorry about that, thought you were talking about the reset password redirection. To handle the redirect after sending the email, you will take a similar approach and modify your `ForgotPasswordController` and override the `sendResetLinkEmail` function instead:

```
class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{
    use SendsPasswordResetEmails {
        sendResetLinkEmail as unused;
    }

    ...

    public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateEmail($request);

        $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
            $request->only('email')
        );

        //Return the response
        if ($response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT) {
            return response()->json(array(
                'result' => 'ok',
            ), 200);
        } else {
            return response()->json(array(
                'result' => 'fail',
            ), 500);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: My Ajax trigger password/request and password/email is also triggered. At the end, I'm not redirect to /login as before, I'm redirect to password/email and I see json in plain text.

Comment: I think there's a confusion. I need to avoid redirection on 'send reset email' not on 'reset password'. Answer still the same ?

Comment: I've got provisional header and just after login page reload :/

Comment: Verify your routes are correct (e.g. `php artisan route:list`). Your ajax call posts to `password/request` although the default route is `password/email`. The controller function should be `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail`

Comment: Ok it works ! Here my problem that I corriged : remove action from form tag / proper serialized data from form. Thank for your help

Comment: Awesome. Glad to hear you got it working. Happy to help.